# What's the best way i can iterate over a hash in this manner?

Tags: ruby, loops, hash, combinations, key-value

so i have this hash and i want to write a program that, given a person’s score can tell them:

**a)** whether or not they’re allergic to a given item

**b)** the full list of allergies.

```
allergies = {
        1 => "eggs",               
        2 => "peanuts",            
        4 => "shellfish",         
        8 => "strawberries",   
        16 => "tomatoes", 
        32 => "chocolate", 
        64 => "pollen", 
        128 => "cat",
    }
```

I thought about how i would achieve this. see the comments below.

```
 # 1+2 = eggs & peanuts (3)        # 1+2+4 = eggs & peanuts & shellfish (7)         # 1+2+4+8 = eggs & peanuts & shellfish & strawberries (15)
 # 1+4 = eggs & shellfish (5)      # 1+2+8 = eggs & peanuts & strawberries (11)     # 1+2+4+16 = eggs & peanuts & shellfish & tomatoes (23)
 # 1+8 = eggs & strawberries (9)   # 1+2+16 = eggs & peanuts & tomatoes (19)        # 1+2+4+32 = eggs & peanuts & shellfish & chocolate (39)
 # 1+16 = eggs & tomatoes (17)     # 1+2+32 = eggs & peanuts & chocolate (35)       # 1+2+4+64 = eggs & peanuts & shellfish & pollen (71)
 # 1+32 = eggs & chocolate (33)    # 1+2+64 = eggs & peanuts & pollen (67)          # 1+2+4+128 = eggs & peanuts & shellfish & cat (135)
 # 1+64 = eggs & pollen (65)       # 1+2+128 = eggs & peanuts & car (131)           #etc
 # 1+128 = eggs & cat (129)
```

so what i could use help with is, how can i iterate over the hash, making sure all **255** possible combinations be accounted for and return the key associated with that possible combination, so that when i call the method with **35** parameter, it will return the values ["eggs", "peanuts", "chocolate"].
hope that makes sense.

I'm open to other ideas you may have to achieve this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
allergies = {
   1 => "eggs",               
   2 => "peanuts",            
   4 => "shellfish",        
   8 => "strawberries",
  16 => "tomatoes"  
}
```

```
def nbr_to_allergies(allergies, n)
  allergies.values_at(*allergies.keys.select { |k| n & k == k })
end
```

```
puts "nbr    allergies"
puts "-" * 64
(0..2**(allergies.size)-1).each do |n|
  puts "#{n.to_s.rjust(2)}: #{nbr_to_allergies(allergies, n)}"
end
```

displays the following.

```
nbr    allergies
----------------------------------------------------------------
 0: []
 1: ["eggs"]
 2: ["peanuts"]
 3: ["eggs", "peanuts"]
 4: ["shellfish"]
 5: ["eggs", "shellfish"]
 6: ["peanuts", "shellfish"]
 7: ["eggs", "peanuts", "shellfish"]
 8: ["strawberries"]
 9: ["eggs", "strawberries"]
10: ["peanuts", "strawberries"]
11: ["eggs", "peanuts", "strawberries"]
12: ["shellfish", "strawberries"]
13: ["eggs", "shellfish", "strawberries"]
14: ["peanuts", "shellfish", "strawberries"]
15: ["eggs", "peanuts", "shellfish", "strawberries"]
16: ["tomatoes"]
17: ["eggs", "tomatoes"]
18: ["peanuts", "tomatoes"]
19: ["eggs", "peanuts", "tomatoes"]
20: ["shellfish", "tomatoes"]
21: ["eggs", "shellfish", "tomatoes"]
22: ["peanuts", "shellfish", "tomatoes"]
23: ["eggs", "peanuts", "shellfish", "tomatoes"]
24: ["strawberries", "tomatoes"]
25: ["eggs", "strawberries", "tomatoes"]
26: ["peanuts", "strawberries", "tomatoes"]
27: ["eggs", "peanuts", "strawberries", "tomatoes"]
28: ["shellfish", "strawberries", "tomatoes"]
29: ["eggs", "shellfish", "strawberries", "tomatoes"]
30: ["peanuts", "shellfish", "strawberries", "tomatoes"]
31: ["eggs", "peanuts", "shellfish", "strawberries", "tomatoes"]
```

See [Hash#values_at](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Hash.html#method-i-values_at) and [Integer#&](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Integer.html#method-i-26).

Comment: Wow! thanks for helping me with this. This was a tricky question for me and now i have a launching pad to play around and discover new approaches! :)

Answer (score 1):

```
combinations = 1.upto(allergies.keys.length).map do |i|
  allergies.values.combination(i).to_a
end.flatten(1)
# => 255 combinations

lookup_hash = combinations.each_with_object({}) do |combo, memo|
  sum = combo.map do |allergy|
    allergies.key(allergy)
  end.sum
  memo[sum] = combo
end

lookup_hash[35]
# => ["eggs", "peanuts", "chocolate"]
```

To start off, we get all the combinations using the handy [Array#combination](https://apidock.com/ruby/Array/combination) method.

Next, we turn that array-of-arrays into a hash, which maps the sum (e.g. 35) to the specific combination of ingredients. We make use of [Hash#key](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.2/Hash.html#method-i-key) to find the key in the ingredients hash (a number) corresponding to a specific value (a string).

Now that we have that hash, we can lookup any of the numbers.

Comment: Consider using `flat_map` and `allergies.length` rather than `allergies.keys.length`.

Comment: Wow! thanks for helping me with this. This was a tricky question for me and now i have a launching pad to play around and discover new approaches! :)

Answer (score 1):

Since you are effectively dealing with a bitset here, you can use bitwise logic. Specifically, you can use the bitwise `AND` operator with a suitable mask to check whether a certain bit is set in your input.

In your case, you can use your `allergy` keys as a bitmask directly. The numbers you have chosen there have in common that they can be stored in a single byte and each of them have a single bit set at a unique position when represented in binary.

This allows you to check whether this bit is set in the input by using the bitwise `AND` operator (which is available in Ruby as [the `&` operator on Integers](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Integer.html#method-i-26)):

```
35 & 32
# => 32

35 & 16
# => 0
```

This can be used in a pretty simple method using `Enumerable#filter_map` available since Ruby 2.7:

```
ALLERGIES = {
  1 => "eggs",               
  2 => "peanuts",            
  4 => "shellfish",         
  8 => "strawberries",   
  16 => "tomatoes", 
  32 => "chocolate", 
  64 => "pollen", 
  128 => "cat",
}

def get_allergies(allergy_number)
  ALLERGIES.filter_map { |key, value| value if allergy_number & key > 0 }
end

get_allergies(35)
# => ["eggs", "peanuts", "chocolate"]
```

You can use similar logic to check whether a given `allergy_number` indicates a specific named allergy:

```
def allergic?(allergy_number, allergy)
  key = ALLERGIES.key(allergy)

  # return false for unknown allergies
  return false unless key

  allergy_number & key > 0
end

allergic(35, "chocolate")
# => true

allergic(35, "shellfish")
# => false
```

Similarly, you can use a bitwise `OR` operation to generate the `allergy_number` based on a given list of allergies (which is available in Ruby as [the `|` operator on Integers](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Integer.html#method-i-7C)):

```
def allergy_number(allergies)
  allergies.inject(0) do |result, allergy|
    result | (ALLERGIES.key(allergy) || 0)
  end
end

allergy_number ["eggs", "peanuts", "chocolate"]
# => 35
```

Comment: Nice illustration of the use of `filter_map`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have stored your allergy pattern in an integer variable *ap*, i.e. for your example

```
ap = 35
```

You can get the allergies for this pattern using

```
allergie_description = ap
                       .to_s(2) # convert into bit string
                       .split(//) # turn into array
                       .reverse # process right-to-left
                       .map # get position of "1" bits:
                       .with_index {|bit, pos| bit == '1' ? pos : nil}
                       .compact # remove "0" bits
                       .map {|pos| allergies[1<<pos]} # fetch allergy
                       .join(', ') # format nicely
```

This uses the fact that your hash keys basically denote bit positions (`.to_s(2)` creates a bit-string), counted from up from 1.

You can also use this approach to precompute all possible combinations, as you requested in your question (by looping over all possible integers in the desired range), but if new allergies are added, the number of combinations could become so large that it is better to calculate the combined value on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach

```
allergies = {
  1 => "eggs",               
  2 => "peanuts",            
  4 => "shellfish",         
  8 => "strawberries",   
  16 => "tomatoes", 
  32 => "chocolate", 
  64 => "pollen", 
  128 => "cat",
}

def allergies_by_sum_of_keys(allergies, sum)
  allergies_keys = allergies.keys
  lookup = {} 
 
  (1..allergies_keys.length).each do |i|
    allergies_keys.combination(i).to_a.each do |keys|
      lookup[keys.sum] = keys.collect{|key| allergies[key] }
    end
  end
  
  lookup[sum] 
end

allergies_by_sum_of_keys(35)

["eggs", "peanuts", "chocolate"]
```